# How to exclude my own Activity from Activity.startActivity(Intent) chooser?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, intentfilter

My app works with pictures. It can take multiple pictures as an input, process them, and send them again to another app.

As a consequence, my main `Activity` has declared an intent filter on `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` for `image/*` mimetypes and can result in issuing a new `Intent` with the same action and data type using `Activity.startActivity(Intent)`.

Is there a way to exclude my own activity from the list of apps that is displayed to the user after the `startActivity()` call ?

Comment: Can you  include an extra in your intents that you can check?

Comment: I have been thinking about something like this, but all I can imagine is a test to check that my Activity has been re-started by itself. I would prefer to prevent the  user from event seeing this choice in the list. Though, I think I'll implement such a workaround as a quick fix and then explore CommonsWare's answer to implement my own chooser.

Comment: You can migrate my solution for URL intents (http://stackoverflow.com/a/37988201/1185087) it uses an activity-alias to enable and disable the receiving of intents...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not directly, AFAIK. However, you could create your own chooser using `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivityOptions()`, which does allow for filtering yourself (or other things) out.

Comment: Thanks, I started exploring this solution and I should be able to achieve what I want. That would be a nice standard feature to include to android api, though.

Comment: @Kevin Gaudin: Agreed, though it is a bit of a fringe case, so I am not shocked that they do not offer it.

Comment: Can someone who did this please provide a snippet so others can see in general how it was implemented?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is:

Query the available apps to handle the intent.

- If there is a default activity to handle it, which does not belong to your app, open it directly (using `startActivity()`).
- Otherwise, display an intent chooser excluding the package of your own app. So even if your app is set as the default app to handle such intents, the chooser will still be shown, which is what you want.

[Here's a blog post](https://codedogg.wordpress.com/2018/11/09/how-to-exclude-your-own-activity-from-activity-startactivityintent-chooser/) explaining it in a bit greater detail.

Or copy-paste the code directly:

```
/**
 * Attempts to start an activity to handle the given intent, excluding activities of this app.
 * <ul>
 *     <li>If the user has set a default activity (which does not belong in this app's package), it is opened without prompt.</li>
 *     <li>Otherwise, an intent chooser is displayed that excludes activities of this app's package.</li>
 * </ul>
 *
 * @param context context
 * @param intent intent to open
 * @param chooserTitle the title that will be displayed for the intent chooser in case one needs to be displayed.
 */
static void startActivityExcludingOwnApp(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent, @NonNull String chooserTitle) {

    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    List<Intent> possibleIntents = new ArrayList<>();

    Set<String> possiblePackageNames = new HashSet<>();
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)) {

        String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
        if (!packageName.equals(context.getPackageName())) {

            Intent possibleIntent = new Intent(intent);
            possibleIntent.setPackage(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
            possiblePackageNames.add(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);

            possibleIntents.add(possibleIntent);
        }
    }

    @Nullable ResolveInfo defaultResolveInfo = packageManager.resolveActivity(intent, 0);

    if (defaultResolveInfo == null || possiblePackageNames.isEmpty()) {
        throw new ActivityNotFoundException();
    }

    // If there is a default app to handle the intent (which is not this app), use it.
    if (possiblePackageNames.contains(defaultResolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName)) {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
    else { // Otherwise, let the user choose.
        Intent intentChooser = Intent.createChooser(possibleIntents.remove(0), chooserTitle);
        intentChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, possibleIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
        context.startActivity(intentChooser);
    }
}
```