# Android WebView sometimes shows the browser choice screen

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

On create of my activity I am firing a loading handler (whilst a spinner is shown), amongst other things in that handler code I call loadURL on three private WebView objects.

The purpose of this is to pre-cache these webpages, each it then shown dependent on a button touch event. The actual loading and displaying is working fine, except that sometimes (can't see a pattern yet) I (or my testers) get browser choice screen (such as Chrome / Firefox) for no reason.

So my first question is what would cause that, and how to prevent it from happening?

Otherwise how else would you perform the following:

1. Pre-cache the result of three webpages (simple HTML, tables etc with no images).
2. Dependent on a button touch display the result of the webpage in a layout on screen (same layout each time, so when button 2 is touched it's corresponding webpage replaces the previous one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never like answering my own questions, but as the only answer wasn't relevant to the question.

It seems that the problem was caused by a redirect, the webpage being loaded did not actually have a redirect it it, but the server was performing an internal redirect from a sub-domain. I got around the problem with the following code.

```
this.wvBasic.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    private String pendingUrl;

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        if (pendingUrl == null) {
            pendingUrl = url;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if (!url.equals(pendingUrl)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Detected HTTP redirect " + pendingUrl + "->" + url);
            pendingUrl = null;
        }
    }
});
this.wvBasic.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

A Simple Solution is:

```
// Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Source: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/gettingstarted

Answer (score 0):

It is a perfectly normal behavior. You create an `intent`, and the operating system is searching for an activity with a proper `intent-filter` to handle that `startActivity(intent)`. Since there are more applications that can handle your intent (in your case more browsers), the operating system offers you the possibility to choose from these activities.

Now, I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955786/how-to-exclude-my-own-activity-from-activity-startactivityintent-chooser) thread, and it seems to be the info you are looking for. According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivityOptions%28android.content.ComponentName,%20android.content.Intent[],%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29), you can `retrieve a set of activities that should be presented to the user as similar options`. If you are able to filter on these activities such that your app uses the **built-in browser** (which is guaranteed to be installed on all devices), you're good to go.

Comment: I'm not actually firing an intent with the webview. They are dynamically added as child views of an existing LinearLayout view. On touch of a button the relevant WebView is added as a child to the LinearLayout (having first removed the exiting child). It is the act of adding that WebView that seems to sometimes fire the choice screen.

Comment: What do you mean by sometimes?

Comment: It is a bug that I find hard to replicate. You can use the app selecting each of the three buttons (and seeing the relevant webviews) one time. but the next time it will show you the browser choice. This happens on several phones, although all are running ICS>

Comment: Are the URLs that are launching the browser selection redirecting to another url?

Comment: Most likely that is the case.

Comment: Well if it is that redirection in being pick up as an intent by the browsers which is why its launching the selection. The easy work around for this is to load the url that the webview is redirected too. But i just want to clarify, if this is what is happening.

Comment: I have just checked the code our webdeveloper has used and there was a chance that this could happen. For now (to prove the issue) I have removed that code and will see what happens. I will post back here when I have given it enough time "to happen again"!!